# Proving a sequence formula using induction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

Suppose for $T_n$:

$$T_n=(n+4)T_{n-1}-4nT_{n-2}+(4n-8)T_{n-3}$$

$$T_0=2,\quad T_1=3,\quad T_2=6$$

For integer, $n \ge 3$

I conjectured that:

$$T_n = 2^n + n!$$

**The above is actually TRUE.**

Using induction I have to **prove** that.

How do I go about proving:

$$T_{n+1} = 2^{n+1} + (n+1)!$$

Of course I will use:

$$T_n=(n+4)T_{n-1}-4nT_{n-2}+(4n-8)T_{n-3}$$

But can I for example change:

$$T_{n} = 2^{n} + n!$$

And let $n \to n-1$ to get:

$$T_{n-1} = 2^{n-1} + (n-1)!$$

**I would say no? Because I havent yet proved $T_n$, so how can I change $n \to n-1$**?

Thanks!

Comment: The scheme of induction that you need to use is not that of assuming the proposition for the previous step only. In this case you assume that it is true for the previous three steps and show that it is true for the next. This scheme of induction would require to check $3$ initial cases $T_0,T_1,T_2$. Alternatively, or rather equivalently, you can use the scheme of [strong induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction).  This allows you to assume the proposition is true for all previous steps.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy, this question was inspired from there.

Comment: My guess for this would be to use strong induction.  Since we're dealing with terms that are not only 1 less than the term we are trying to prove, but also 2 less and 3 less.  That's why strong induction makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're going to use a form of induction known as strong induction (at least in my graph theory class it is known as this).  Instead of only assuming the term (n-1) holds true, we will assume that all cases are valid for integers less than n.  However, we still need a base case which was missing from your attempt.  $T_3 = (3+4)*6 -4*3*3 +4*2 = 14 = 2^3 +3!$, thus we can proceed with our induction.  To make things absolutely clear, we are going to assume that your formula $T_n = 2^n +n!$ holds true for all integers less than n.  Thus, by our induction hypothesis.  $$T_{n-1} =2^{n-1} + (n-1)! $$$$T_{n-2} =2^{n-2} + (n-2)! $$ $$T_{n-3} = 2^{n-3} + (n-3)!$$
Okay, now we're all set up.  We know that $T_n =(n+4)T_{n-1}-4nT_{n-2}+(4n-8)T_{n-3}$.  Substituting the equations we got from our induction hypothesis yields:  $$T_n=(n+4)(2^{n-1}+(n-1)!) -4n(2^{n-2}+(n-2)!)+(4n-8)(2^{n-3}+(n-3)!)$$ $$ = n! +n2^{n-1} + n^{n+1} + 4(n-1)!-n2^n-4n(n-2)! +n2^{n-1}+4n(n-3)!-2^n-8(n-3)!$$Yes, this is getting quite messy, but notice that we have a $2^{n+1}-2^n = 2^n$.  Substituting this, we arrive at: $$T_n= n! +2^n+n2^{n-1} +  4(n-1)!-n2^n-4n(n-2)! +n2^{n-1}+4n(n-3)!-8(n-3)!$$After some algebra, you will see that all the terms of the equation except the first 2 actually combine to zero, which gives us the correct equation for $T_n$.  If you really want to see it, leave me a comment and i'll supply you with the steps I took, but it is so much more satisfying to get it by yourself.  Good luck!

Comment: I am confused. @user. Here: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs173/sp2009/lectures/lect_18.pdf  It says I have to prove $P(k+1)$ is true? On Page 2 it says that. I assume, $P(0) ... P(n-2), P(n-1), P(n)$ is true. I prove $P(n+1)$ is true. But you are trying to prove $P(n) = T_n$ is true? Isnt that the assumption (+1)?

Comment: I'm not assuming P(n) is true as you did in your attempt.  I assume any integer less than n is true, thus i complete the induction by showing P(n) is true.  If you assume P(n) is true, then yes you need to show P(n+1) is true.